# Suppose $log_{5}(11)=b$ Use change-of-base formula & properties of logs to rewrite each expression in terms of a and b. Show the steps for solving.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Screen shot of the exercise I'm working on (exercise 27):
[image]

I am able to arrive at an equation of the form $\frac{1}{b}=...$

I'd like to check if I'm on the right track and also how to get the expression for a whole $b$, not it's reciprocal like I currently have:

My working:
$$\log_{11}(5)=\frac{\log_5(5)}{\log_5(11)}$$

Since $\log_5(11) = b$:
$$\frac{\log_5(5)}{b}=\log_{11}(5)$$
$$\frac{1}{b}=\log_{11}(5)$$

Am I on the right track? How can I express my left hand side as a whole $b$ rather than $\frac{1}{b}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's completely correct. The questions asks you to write your answer in terms of $a$ and $b,$ so $1/b$ is completely valid. No need to worry that your answer isn't in the form $kb$ (or similar). In fact, there's no simpler way to write $1/b$ unless I'm missing something.